# Inequality of Floor function

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor $ be the floor function.
Is it truth that $|\lfloor ax \rfloor -\lfloor ay \rfloor |\leq |\lfloor bx \rfloor -\lfloor by \rfloor |$ for any real numbers $x,y$ and positive numbers $a\leq b$ ?

By the graph of floor functions, i feel it is true, but i can't prove this. Does someone know the reference to see this is correct or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result does not hold. Try $a=0.5$, $b=0.8$, $x = 1.8$, $y=2.2$. Below you can see the graph of
$$
g(x,y)=\left| \lfloor ax\rfloor - \lfloor ay\rfloor\right|-\left| \lfloor bx\rfloor - \lfloor by\rfloor\right|
$$

for the mentioned values of $a,b$. In the blue portions the inequality is not valid.

[image]

Comment: Thank  you for your answer and the nice graph.

Comment: +1 for the excellent graphics.  By the way, which software did you use to create the graphics?

Comment: @user2661923 The graphic was obtained using Wolfram Mathematica.